# Confusion about using beefy?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I found it's confusing to use beefy.

1. I have an app.js file, and I have the index.html with a script's
   src="./bundle.js". So I run following command:

   ```
   beefy app.js:bundle.js --live
   ```

   I want to use beefy to generate bundle.js and reload it everytime I
   change anything. But beefy just doesn't generate the bundle.js file
   for me. I open localhost page, all I got is bundle.js
   not found.
2. Does beefy set up a simple local host at port 9966? what's it for?
   And why everytime I has to refresh the localhost page to make every
   work?
3. If I have to use browserify to generate the bundle.js file, why to
   use beefy?
4. It's document says all arguments after -- will pass to browserify,
   so I tried following:

   ```
   beefy app.js:bundle.js 9999 -- -o bundle.js
   ```

   it still doesn't work. No bundle.js file is generating.
5. Finally, I use browserify to generate the bundle.js and have
   index.html ready, and I run:

   ```
   beefy app.js:bundle.js --live
   ```

   And I change my code, refresh my page. Yes, the page reflects the changes. When I looked into the bundle.js file generated, I see the code remains unchanged. But the bundle.js that browser loaded is new!! I don't know where this new bundle.js is stored.

It's just so confusing to use beefy and it lacks good document, can anyone help?
I just want to live reload my bundle.js file.

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
beefy app.js:bundle.js --live
```

The browserified bundle should be at:

```
localhost:9966/bundle.js
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The document is indeed confusing, have you tried --browserify flag.

```
cd yourappdir
beefy app.js:bundle.js --live --browserify
```

Also I start using watchify https://github.com/substack/watchify for live bundle update. Beefy seems not be able to function as a simple file watcher reliably.

Answer (score 0):

3 years late into the game but, for me, [budo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/budo) works just fine:

> budo app.js:bundle.js --live